# Using Command Line Script to push file into Azure DevOps Repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Please let me know what I'm I missing. Just wanted to create a pipeline to push any file up to the repo, But when I try it, is giving me the following error, even though I uploaded a file to the clone repo.

**Error saying:** nothing to commit. working tree clean 
[image]

The script I'm using
[image]

I double check running git status on Windows Terminal.
[image: Using Windows Terminal]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your pipelines shouldn't need to be committing anything. That said, the pipeline's output is telling you the problem: It's checking out a *commit*, not a *branch*, which means you have a detached HEAD. You need to checkout a branch before you commit changes.

Comment: Thank you for your response Daniel. My apologize for the question. Hopefully i can explain myself clearly. When a user upload a file, instead on them running the git commands all they need to do is run the pipeline to upload the file for them. 1. git status, 2. git add. 3. git commit -m "Whatever" 4. git push

Comment: That is absolutely not going to work. The user's changes have to be in the repository before the pipeline can be aware of them, at which point the commands you're trying to run are redundant because the changes are **already in the repo**.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @o2webdev, how are things going? Is `@DanielMann`'s suggestion helpful to you to solve the problem? If it is helpful, could you please post an answer with the summary of your solution? this may be also very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @bright-ran-msft, suggestion was helpful. Still looking for some type of solution/automation to help out my team members to upload large *.pbix file into a Azure DevOps Repo.

Comment: Hi @o2webdev, for large files, maybe you can consider using [**Git Large File Storage (LFS)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops). Generally a Git repository on Azure Repos should be no larger than 10GB. This aims to ensure reliability and availability for all customers. For more details, you can see "[**Git limits**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops)".